# Number of unread messages sum

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I want to retrieve messages and number of unread message (0) for a sender and dest in a conversation.

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                          messages                             |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| message_id | id_sender | id_dest |  subject | message | read  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|       1    |     25    |     50  |    Hi    | message |  0    |
|       2    |     25    |     50  |    Hi2   |message2 |  1    |
|       3    |     25    |     50  |    Hi3   |message3 |  0    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In this case the result must be 2. I try with

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT message,sum(read = 0) as nm_messages
    FROM messages 
    WHERE ( id_sender = id1 AND id_dest = id2 ) or
          ( id_dest = id1 AND id_sender = id2 )
    ORDER BY message_id DESC
    LIMIT 10) AS ttbl
ORDER BY message_id ASC
```

The messages part is ok but when

I add

```
 sum(read = 0) as nm_messages
```

return only the firsth message if possible for both mysql postgresql
Thanks!

Comment: And, you want the *number of unread messages* for ... each row? ... a separate row, where all the other columns are `NULL`? ... in some other format?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @pozs the more efficentand costless way

Comment: SUM(CASE WHEN read = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as nm_messages

Answer (score -1):

I have used PostgreSQL 9.4.11, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit.

With distinct on you can eliminate same rows with their unique ids. in this case i have used id_sender.

> SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal

more information look at this link:
[distinct on](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

Below sql query will return only the first message and the number of unread messages (0):

```
SELECT distinct on (id_Sender) 
       message,
       count(case when read=0 then 1 end) over() as nm_messages
FROM messages
group by id_Sender,message,message_id
order by id_Sender,message_id
```

message | nm_message

message | 2

Answer (score -2):

You should use the sum with if condition. Should be like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(message),sum(IF(read = 0,1,0)) as nm_messages
    FROM messages 
    WHERE ( id_sender = id1 AND id_dest = id2 ) or
          ( id_dest = id1 AND id_sender = id2 )
    GROUP BY id_sender, id_dest
    LIMIT 10) AS ttbl
ORDER BY message_id ASC
```

When the condition is true (read = 1), then it will sum up 1, otherwise 0.

I just saw that there was no grouping in the query. I added that. Also if you use an aggregate function, it doesnt make sense to do that only for one field (read), and not for others (message). So i put group_concact around message. That makes more sense to me?!

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
 manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read = 0,1,0

Comment: Downvoting because you dont understand sql? Good job